# AWS Typescript CDK, Trying to add kinesis stream as a source to firehose

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I am trying to to do this flow:

DynamoDB -> Kinesis data stream -> Kinesis firehose -> S3 -> Redshift

I tried this in console and everything works perfectly, however when I tried to write as a code using was typescript CDK, I am getting this error

```
Resource handler returned message: "KinesisSourceStreamConfig is only applicable for KinesisStreamAsSource stream type. (Service: Firehose, Status Code: 400, Request ID: c3b3
9dc4-c6a7-3c31-9a00-68c863659e53, Extended Request ID: bgcK523kXRumygU0/xX5cjDlUZgF6LLwSYo7sqyfQ2GIjzW9kJGWY3ZFm9pHoZlPuLanXnLlSqOr3xhyfHIEW7GYONByP5Fe)" (RequestToken: 1c9c1
56b-c2a4-9600-28f5-52af5664e3bb, HandlerErrorCode: InvalidRequest)
```

Here is the code I am trying to implement:

```
import * as cdk from '@aws-cdk/core';
import * as s3 from '@aws-cdk/aws-s3';
import * as dynamodb from '@aws-cdk/aws-dynamodb';
import * as kinesis from '@aws-cdk/aws-kinesis';
import * as  firehose from '@aws-cdk/aws-kinesisfirehose';
import * as iam from "@aws-cdk/aws-iam";
import { CfnResource } from '@aws-cdk/core';

const DynamoDBArn = 'arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:207627709836:table/blog-srsa-ddb-table';

export class DynamoStreamer extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor(
    scope: cdk.Construct,
    id: string
  ) {
    super(scope, id);
    const bucket = new s3.Bucket(this, 'data-lake', {
      publicReadAccess: false
    });
    const dataStream=new kinesis.Stream(this,"dataStream",{shardCount:1,streamName:"stevensu_cdk_stream"})

    const myTable = new dynamodb.Table(this, 'dynamo-table', {
      tableName: 'blog-srsa-ddb-table2',
      partitionKey: { name: 'id', type: dynamodb.AttributeType.STRING },
      sortKey: { name: 'name', type: dynamodb.AttributeType.STRING },
      removalPolicy: cdk.RemovalPolicy.RETAIN,
      kinesisStream: dataStream
    });

    const deliveryStreamRole = new iam.Role(this, `DeliveryStreamRole`, {
      assumedBy: new iam.ServicePrincipal("firehose.amazonaws.com"),
    });


    const firehoseDeliveryStream = new firehose.CfnDeliveryStream(this, 'Delivery Stream', {
      redshiftDestinationConfiguration: {
        clusterJdbcurl: 'jdbc:redshift://redshift-cluster-1.cicrdvtr7ouk.us-east-1.redshift.amazonaws.com:5439/dev',
        username: 'admin',
        password: '2131636+aA',
        roleArn: 'arn:aws:iam::207627709836:role/service-role/KinesisFirehoseServiceRole-KDS-RED-vTWqG-us-east-1-1630965194702',
        copyCommand: {
          dataTableName: 'users_test',
          copyOptions: 'format as json \'auto\''
        },
        s3Configuration: {
          bucketArn: bucket.bucketArn,
          roleArn: deliveryStreamRole.roleArn
        },
      },
      kinesisStreamSourceConfiguration: {
        kinesisStreamArn: dataStream.streamArn,
        roleArn: deliveryStreamRole.roleArn
      },

    });
  }
}
```

The error is happening in this part of code:

```
 kinesisStreamSourceConfiguration: {
        kinesisStreamArn: dataStream.streamArn,
        roleArn: deliveryStreamRole.roleArn
      },
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure on better ways to do this, but the error comes from the fact that you need to include the `deliveryStreamType`  key in the CfnDeliveryStream instance and set it to `kinesisStreamAsSource`.

See also the cfn docs on the allowed values: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-kinesisfirehose-deliverystream.html#cfn-kinesisfirehose-deliverystream-deliverystreamtype

Comment: Yeah, it worked, thanks! I don't know why I haven't read about this property